How can I use setTimeout to handle when a user stops typing? I'm trying to implement typing indicators in a real-time chat app
I'm nearly finished putting together a real-time chat app that uses a Django channels consumer and a React front-end. I've implemented typing indicators in the handleTyping and handleNewChat hook functions, and it's mostly working with the exception of some unexpected behavior. When a user starts typing, the notification appears on the recipient's screen as expected, but after sustained typing, the typing indicator starts blinking on and off. After console logging the isTyping state, I'm seeing the handleTyping hook ignore the setTimeout block and immediately change the isTyping state back to false. Being a bit new to React, this one has me scratching my head and any help is greatly appreciated.
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

import axios from "axios";

function ChatRoom({ serverURL, recipientId }) {
  const ws = useRef(null);
  let typingTimeout = null;

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [newMessageLoading, setNewMessageLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [isTyping, setIsTyping] = useState({});

  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null);
  const [recipient, setRecipient] = useState(null);
  const [chatHistory, setChatHistory] = useState([]);
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");

  const token = localStorage.getItem("Token");

  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const currentUserResponse = await axios.get(
        `http://${serverURL}/user/token/${token}`
      );
      setCurrentUser(currentUserResponse.data);

      const recipientResponse = await axios.get(
        `http://${serverURL}/user/id/${recipientId}`
      );
      setRecipient(recipientResponse.data);

      const chatroomResponse = await axios.get(
        `http://${serverURL}/chatroom/${token}/${recipientId}`
      );

      if (!chatroomResponse) {
        setChatHistory([]);
      } else {
        const messagesResponse = await axios.get(
          `http://${serverURL}/chatroom/${chatroomResponse.data.id}/messages`
        );
        setChatHistory(messagesResponse.data);
      }

      setLoading(false);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching data: ", error);
      setError(error);
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  const handleNewChat = async () => {
    axios
      .get(`http://${serverURL}/test_token`, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Token ${token}`,
        },
      })
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.data.split(" ")[0] === "Passed") {
          try {
            ws.current = new WebSocket(
              `ws://${serverURL}/ws/socket-server/?token=${token}&recipient=${recipientId}`
            );

            ws.current.onopen = () => {
              console.log("Websocket connection established.");
            };

            ws.current.onmessage = (event) => {
              const message = JSON.parse(event.data);
              const type = message.type;

              if (type === "chat.typing") {
                setIsTyping(message);
              } else {
                const newMessage = message;
                setChatHistory((prevChatHistory) => [
                  newMessage,
                  ...prevChatHistory,
                ]);

                setNewMessageLoading(false);
              }
            };
          } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
          }
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setError(error);
        console.error(error);
      });
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setNewMessageLoading(true);
    if (ws.current && ws.current.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
      ws.current.send(
        JSON.stringify({
          type: "chat_message",
          token: token,
          recipientId: recipientId,
          message: message,
        })
      );
    }
    setMessage("");
  };

  const handleTyping = () => {
    clearTimeout(typingTimeout);

    if (!ws.current || ws.current.readyState !== WebSocket.OPEN) {
      return;
    }

    ws.current.send(
      JSON.stringify({
        type: "chat_typing",
        token: token,
        recipientId: recipientId,
        is_typing: true,
      })
    );

    typingTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
      ws.current.send(
        JSON.stringify({
          type: "chat_typing",
          token: token,
          recipientId: recipientId,
          is_typing: false,
        })
      );
    }, 5000);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
    handleNewChat();
  }, [serverURL, recipientId]);

  return (
    <>
      {console.log(isTyping.is_typing)}
      {loading || newMessageLoading ? (
        <p className="loading">Loading...</p>
      ) : (
        <div className="chatroom">
          <div className="chat-title">
            <h3>Chat with {recipient.username}</h3>
          </div>
          <div className="feed">
            {isTyping.is_typing === false ||
            isTyping.sender === currentUser.username ? null : (
              <p className="typing-indicator">{isTyping.message}</p>
            )}

            {chatHistory.length === 0 ? (
              <p>Get chatting...</p>
            ) : (
              chatHistory.map((message) => (
                <div
                  className={
                    currentUser.id === message.sender
                      ? "message-user"
                      : "message"
                  }
                  key={message.id}
                >
                  <div className="message-content">
                    <h4>
                      {currentUser.id === message.sender
                        ? "You"
                        : recipient.username}
                    </h4>
                    <p>{message.content}</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              ))
            )}
          </div>
          <div className="message-form">
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <input
                autoFocus
                className="message-input"
                type="text"
                value={message}
                onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}
                onKeyDown={handleTyping}
              />
              <input className="send-btn" type="submit" value="Send" />
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
}

export default ChatRoom;


Let me guess, the blinking starts after about 5 seconds? Log out the id of the timeout (ie typingTimeout after setTimeout() and before clearTimeout. When everything goes right, two subsequent logs always must have the same value. I suspect, the value of typingTimeout getting lost somewhere,  so that an existing timout cannot be cleared ...

typingTimeout should be a ref. Now it's just get destroyed every time a component is rendered, so clearTimeout does nothing

@derpirscher Can you elaborate on the id of the timeout? I wasn't aware that the typingTimeout had an id property that could be referenced.

It hasn't. The typingTimeout itself is the id (if you inspect it at runtime, you will see it's in fact a number) you need to clear the timeout again.  But when for instance a rerender happens, the way the variable is currently defined, it's lost, thus the clearTimeout won't work anymore ...
